# Notification push on blazor-server with signalR

Tags: asp.net-core, push-notification, signalr, blazor-server-side

I am developing an application in blazor-server.

I have already implemented signalR inside it works fine.

I was wondering, how can I implement push notifications, so as to have an alert when the signalR sends a signal and the browser is closed?

For example:
[image]